# binding a negative sign to a value in ocaml

Tags: ocaml, bind, interpreter

Im trying to run an interpreter I made in ocaml and when i to push in a negative value i.e. let e1 = run [PushI -2; PushI 2; LessThan] []. I get an error because it says i am giving the function PushI two arguments, i'm assuming they are talking about the - sign and the two. Because doing (-2) works. What can I change to make PushI -2 a viable input.

code:

```
type stackVal = 
    I of int 

type command = PushI of int 

let rec run (commands : command list) (stack: stackVal list) : stackVal list = 
  match (commands , stack)  with
  | (PushI i :: rest, _              ) -> run rest (I i :: stack)

let to_string (s : stackVal) : string = 
  match s with
  | I i -> string_of_int i 

let parse_command (s:string) : command = 
  match take_while is_alpha (String.trim s) with
  | ("PushI"    , p)  -> let Some i = parse_int (String.trim p)    in PushI i

let parse_int (s : string) : int option = 
  match int_of_string s with  
  | n           -> Some n
  | exception _ -> None
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do `PushI ~-1`. `~-` is unambiguously the `int` negation operator: https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#VAL(~-)

In other words, it doesn't have any parsing ambiguity like `-`.